# Excel Date calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I need to calculate prorated days for real estate closings automatically for the tax prorations. I have everything figured out except I have to manually enter the prorated date. For example, house closes june 1st, it will always calculate days until june 30th. I simply have a formula subtracting june 30th from june 1st to give me number of days, however, i have to constantly monitor the 6/30 date to make sure the year is the following june 30th, I'd like to automate this. how do i enter a formula that says I want this cell to say 6/30/(after todays date)? so, if today is 8/23/19 I want the prorated date to read 6/30/2020. If it were say, 4/30/19, I want the prorated date to read 6/30/19, so always the june 30th after whatever date.

Comment: So you want the prorated date to always be the next 30th June after the date you put in?

Comment: If you want it to do it automatically in the cell after you type, it will need to be in vba.

Comment: So if the input date is **6/30/2020**, you want the output date to be **6/30/2021** ???

Answer (score 2):

With the input date in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1<DATE(YEAR(A1),6,30),DATE(YEAR(A1),6,30),DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,6,30))
```

[image]

Comment: Just seen that 30th June calculates to the next year - This works better and it's neater +1

Comment: @Smock  If 30th June does not roll-over, we would replace **<** with **<=**

Comment: I think the 6/30 is arbitrary.  The idea is that when the user puts in a date it does not automatically assume current year.

Comment: @ScottCraner it does matter if it's before 6/30 - that's why it's important - '*If it were say, 4/30/19, I want the prorated date to read 6/30/19*' <- 30th of June in the same year

Comment: No, I think the user will put in the sale date.  6/30 was only an example not a fixed date. @Smock Not every home will sell on the 1 of july.

Comment: '*so always the june 30th after whatever date*'. He's quite clear with his 4/30/19 example too.

Comment: @Smock "***For example***, house closes june 1st, it will always calculate days until june 30th." Emphasize mine

Comment: @Smock but I will concede I may be wrong.  Just stating my opinion of the question

Comment: Or slightly shorter version: `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+(A1>DATE(YEAR(A1),6,30)),6,30)`

Comment: I think the bench mark is `06/30` and the Year changes `+1`  if input is after date. Also operator should `<=` will protect if Input date is `06/30/2019` or even `A1>` will also works.